# DB2 iSeries AS400 - Database Connection

Tags: c#, database, db2, ibm-midrange

I am having problem connecting to iSeries DB2 using IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries, but I can easily
connect using System.Data.Odbc

Using System.Data.Odbc:

1. I created System DSN - 
   System: 10.33.15.3, DSN Name: mm370lib, Driver: iSeries Access ODBC Driver
2. With C# Odbc connection string: 
   "Dsn=mm370lib;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;"

How do I make a connection using IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries?

Comment: http://warnajith.blogspot.com/2011/02/connecting-db2iseries-from-net.html read this link.you have to install iseries driver on calling machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I have successfully connect using "IBM Client Access OLE DB provider" with connection string format taken from http://www.connectionstrings.com/as-400#p60.

```
Provider=IBMDA400;Data Source=MY_SYSTEM_NAME;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Default Collection=MY_LIBRARY;
```

So my actual connection string using the parameters above is:

```
Provider=IBMDA400;Data Source=10.33.15.3;User Id=ICTDEV;Password=******;Default Collection=mm370lib;
```

I've been using this connection also in my PHP program using COM.

Here is the code snippet:

```
include('application/libraries/adodb5/adodb.inc.php');
$this->db = ADONewConnection('ado');
$dsn = "Provider=IBMDA400;Data Source=10.33.15.3;UserId=ICTDEV;Password=******;Default Collection=mm370lib;";
$this->db->PConnect($dsn);
```

Comment: This absolutely did not work. Still getting Connection String invalid error

Comment: what OS are you using? This only works in windows. Given u have installed iSeries Driver.

Answer (score 2):

Taken directly from [ConnectionStrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/as-400#p62)

ODBC
`Driver={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};System=my_system_name;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;`

NET
`DataSource=myServerAddress;UserID=myUsername;Password=myPassword; DataCompression=True;`

Comment: that is my connection string for odbc, but I would like to use IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries driver. Thanks!

Comment: You can also specify various other options for your DB2 connection such as DefaultCatalog, LibraryList, DataCompression and so on... IBM has a decent reference on that [here](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg246440.pdf)